# Run-time loading DLL with /MT +Unicode in application with /MD +Multibyte?

Tags: c++, windows, loadlibrary

My main program is build with the /MD flag, and "Multi-Byte" Character set.
I have another library, which is build with the /MT flag and "Unicode" Character set, which I'd like to use in my program. Neither the main program, nor the library can be reconfigured without an excessive amount of work and maintenance.

Now, I now that I can't link against the library conventionally, but what if I export some functions from the library, then load it during run-time using [LoadLibrary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibrarya) +[GetProcAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/getprocaddress?view=msvc-170), and then call those functions from my main program? Would that be safe, as long as I don't cross-deallocate any memory? Any pitfalls I'd have to be aware of?

Comment: what are the functions you're going to call? I don't think `LoadLibrary` will get you away from any of the problems you would see when linking directly

Comment: Don't pass anything across the module boundaries except `C` types; don't allocate in one module and deallocate in another; don't even think of passing `std::collection`s (including std::vector and std::(w)string) across the module boundary,

Comment: I'd just call some functions with fundamental parameter types, e.g. `bool some_func(float f,void *p,int i)`. I assume using char* as a parameter would be a problem, but I could get around that. No struct or class objects.

Comment: then you shouldn't see any problems linking to the library at compile time. There shouldn't be a problem using `char*`, its only the c++ standard library you need to avoid

Comment: If you cannot use load-time dynamic linking then you cannot use runtime dynamic linking either. It's not that the latter has fewer requirements than the previous. If you need to use a library that's built with incompatible flags you're going to have to load it into a different process, and implement some sort of IPC. COM remoting is one way to do that.

Comment: Why can't you link against it directly? If its a DLL then it's not an issue. You can't *statically* link to it no, but you can use the lib for the DLL just fine and that will load the DLL automatically at runtime.